# Two ''While'' conditions?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to make a website where it interacts with your name.
When you log on you have to enter your name first, and for that I use a prompt window (Javascript), the problem here is that the user can easily get to the next line of code by simply pressing ''Cancel''.
So I made this:

```
while (userName === "" & userName === null); {userName = prompt("What's your name?")}
```

But after the user presses ''Cancel'' twice, the Javascript just stops entirely.
Here's my entire code, including the HTML for the website. Ignore the HTML :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<title>
Javascript
</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<script>
//Here I'll make a few variables for Javascript to work with.
var accessGranted = false
var userName
var userNameConfirmed = false
var userAge
var userAgeConfirmed = false
userName = prompt("What's your name?")
//Now I'll make a while that has two conditions to run.
while (userName === "" & userName === null); {
userName = prompt("Hvad hedder du?")
}</script>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please review [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) and [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please delete the semicolon here

```
while (userName === "" & userName === null); {
//                                        ^^^ no semicolon
//                    ^^^ change it to ||
```

because the [semicolon separates statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements). The next block is not treated as part of the `while` loop.

Then you need to change the operator to a [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) `||`, because you ask for the name and if empty **or** `null`, the it should promt again.

```js
var accessGranted = false,
    userName,
    userNameConfirmed = false,
    userAge,
    userAgeConfirmed = false;

userName = prompt("What's your name?")

while (userName === "" || userName === null) {
    userName = prompt("Hvad hedder du?");
}
alert(userName);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a dream :D